# Remove an element from an array of doubles and booleans

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to remove an element from an array of doubles. I've tried to use "null" but I can only use null for an array of strings. Here is my code:

```
String[] nome= new String[tamMax];
double[] quanto = new double[tamMax];
double[] preco = new double[tamMax];
boolean[] feito = new boolean[tamMax];
int nItens=0;
for (int i = 0; i < nItens; i++) {
    if (nome[i + 1] == null) {
            nome[i] = null;
            nItens-=1;
            quanto[i]=null;
            feito[i]=null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can't remove an item from an array - once an array is created, it has a fixed size. Even if you could assign a `null` value, you wouldn't be *removing* the array element - you'd just be assigning a `null` value to the element. Instead, I suggest that:

- You create a class to represent the combination of the three aspects here (whatever `quanto`, `preco` and `feito` means. [Creating parallel collections is usually an anti-pattern in my view.](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2014/06/03/anti-pattern-parallel-collections/)
- You use the `List<E>` interface and the `ArrayList<E>` class to represent the collection of items. You *can* remove from a list.

For example, you might have:

```java
public class StockItem {
    private final String name;
    private final BigDecimal price;
    private final int stockLevel;

    public StockItem(String name, BigDecimal price, int stockLevel) {
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
        this.stockLevel = stockLevel;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public BigDecimal getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public int getStockLevel() {
        return stockLevel;
    }
}
```

Then:

```java
List<StockItem> items = new ArrayList<>();
items.add(new StockItem("Guitar", ...));
items.add(new StockItem("Drum kit", ...));

// Remove the guitar element
items.remove(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Because doubles and booleans are primitive types, they cannot be assigned a null object reference. You could make them Double and Boolean (capital d and b) which would then allow you to assign null. Also, you could assign them a base value of false and 0.0, but this might not work depending on your program specifications.